# How to get Grid's child in qml with x and y?

Tags: javascript, qt, grid, qml

How to get Grid's child in qml with x and y points ?

**My Code:-**

```
Grid{
  id:grid
  //some code
}

//some js fn
 grid.at(x,y) = something
```

Answer (score 0):

With `childAt` method, as documented here
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#childAt-method

Comment: It always gives me element at 0,0

Comment: Then write the whole code. Like this it's just a useless question.